# Does a non-wobbling rotating black hole produce gravitational waves if it were to suddenly accelerate its rotation?

Tags: black-holes, acceleration, gravitational-waves

My understanding is anything that have mass and accelerate produce gravitational wave however small, suppose I have a rotating black hole and nothing orbits it and it's spin suddenly accelerates. Does it produce gravitational wave? This is a thought experiment so do not ask me what is the mechanism that causes it to spin faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravitational radiation is produced by a time dependent quadrupole. A spinning black hole does not have a quadrupole moment so it does not produce gravitational radiation.

I'm not sure that it's possible to accelerate the rotation of a spinning black hole without breaking the axial symmetry (e.g. by firing asteroids into it at an angle). In that case you'd get some gravitational radiation from whatever broke the symmetry (the infalling asteroid in this case). If you could somehow speed up the rotation without breaking the axial symmetry there would be no gravitational radiation.

Comment: An accretion disk should spin up a stationary black hole without violating axial symmetry.